# JW Player 6 and Shoutcast v2

Tags: jwplayer, shoutcast, aac+

I'm using JW Player (v6) to broadcast an AAC+ webradio. I can use it with IceCast 2 servers (in my case using the KH branch). Now I'm setting up a new webradio but using a ShoutCast v2 server. I cannot find a way to get it work.

I've tried Muses player. It works but is a bit unstable and have no metatag support for v2, that I need.

Here is a working example of JW Player using IceCast 2:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  autostart: true,
  height: 30,
  width: 400,
  primary: 'flash',
  playlist: [{
    title: 'Live Mix - www.livemix.com.br',
    sources: [{
      file: "http://aac.livemix.com.br:80/livemix?type=.flv",
      type: "flv",
    }]
  }]
});
```

My new webradio in ShoutCast v2 is:

```
http://radio.centraldj.com.br:8000/centraldj
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ShoutCast/IceCast support in Flash/HTML5 is pretty shaky. The JW Player works with some streams, but not others. For this reason, we don't officially support it under our supported formats - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

However, you *might* be able to get it working by using this:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  autostart: true,
  height: 30,
  width: 400,
  primary: 'flash',
  file: "http://radio.centraldj.com.br:8000/centraldj",
  type: "mp3"
});
```

Comment: Hello Ethan, I was expecting your anwser, thank you.
You can browse here: [link](http://www.livemix.com.br/jwplayer/)
It appears to be playing, but no sound. Any ideas? It's your code.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the right code for this to work. Your particular stream might not be supported, though. ShoutCast support is very hit or miss, which is why we don't list it as a supported format in our support guide.

Comment: Ok, thank you Ethan, I think its time to forget AAC+ and use standard MP3 broadcast to be more compatible everywhere.
Just to understand: the problem is specific to ShoutCast/IceCast softwares or AAC+? For MP3 audio live streaming, what server software do you recommend?

Comment: No problem. I think it is AAC+. You can probably use Wowza for live RTMP MP3 Audio.

Answer (score 1):

SHOUTcast (v2 included) is slightly incompatible with HTTP.  You won't be able to get this to work on all platforms.

Also, there aren't any browsers that can handle HE-AAC in the ADTS wrapper, which is why Icecast has the option to send the data as FLV instead.  SHOUTcast doesn't have this functionality.  You could get MP3 streams from SHOUTcast to work on browsers that support it, but not all browsers can play MP3.  In addition, not all browsers will deal with the broken HTTP implementation.

Comment: Thank you, but I can stream this ShoutCast v2 webradio using another player in Flash, Muses [link](http://muses.org). My main question is how to configure JW Player to use ShoutCast v2.

Comment: @Arvy Yes, that's a custom player built to handle SHOUTcast.  JW Player isn't.